# Bug fixes or alternatives for the JavaFX 8 MediaPlayer

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm writting a program that plays mp3 files and requires accurate times for both the currently played time and the total time of the audio. For both the `MediaPlayer` of JFX8 seems to be buggy. The `currentTimeProperty` has sometimes a offset of up to 8 seconds and also the stated total time seem to be incorrect stated if one compares it other programs.

My question is: 
Is it somehow possible to bypass these issues or are there any reliable alternatives to the included `MediaPlayer`?

*The code to get the total duration of the .mp3 file:*

```
duration = player.getMedia().getDuration().toSeconds();
```

Example result (in s): JFX8: 3564.775, Windows Explorer: ~3568

*The code to get the current playtime in Seconds:*

```
Duration currentTime = player.getCurrentTime().toSeconds();
```

Example result (if the file was completely played; in s): JFX8: 3583.734